# regex match two con

Tags: regex

I get a number of flat file feeds that I parse. One of the feeds has a comments field that will frequently contain double quotes.

Which is not a big deal, except for the fact that the file is a pipe delimited double quote qualified file!!

Below I outline the string I get.

```
0|0.9|""|"M"|"X"|"0.2"|"This is the string with the "double" double quotes"
```

Here is the string I would like to have.

```
0|0.9|""|"M"|"X"|"0.2"|"This is the string with the double double quotes"
```

My thought was to use a simple regex
`"(?!\|)(?<!\|)"`

However this still matches the two consecutive double quotes that make up an empty field.

I have also tried

`\|*"\|*`

Which I thought would match any double quote that was not adjacent to a pipe.

But this captures all of the double quotes.

This seems like it should be easy, but I am stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on what criteria were `X` and `0.2` removed?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. I have corrected. The only thing I want removed is the double quotes in the comments field.

Comment: `(?<=\|")(?:[^"|]*"[^"|]*)+(?="(\||$))` returns any delimited values that contain quotes, for a start. http://www.rubular.com/r/yte3svDalb What language are you using?

Comment: Please include the actual question and the runtime environment, Shawn. I presume you want to remove the quotes? Note that answers may contain features that may not be present in all regexp engines.

Comment: it's a find/replace in notepad++ right now. I parse the files in PHP before I process them in SSIS. The problem I have hit is that I the SSIS file parser has no way to handle this. It has transforms that could handle it but the parser blows up before it can pass the line onto hte next part of the integration. So I pre-process them

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly not possible in the general case — what if the comment is `You need to use a pipe ("|") rather than < and >`? — but for the 99% case, you can write:

```
(?<!\|)"(?!\|)
```

to match a double-quote that is neither preceded nor followed by a pipe, or better yet:

```
(?<!\||^)"(?!\||$)
```

to also require that it not be adjacent to either end of the string.

Comment: If the regexp engine can handle zero width look ahead/look behind of course.

Comment: @owlstead: Yes, absolutely. The question included `(?<!`, so I figured that meant it was safe to use, but I probably should have mentioned it explicitly.

Comment: I notice that you reversed the order of the lookahead and lookbehind. Is that sequence important? Thanks, Shawn

Comment: @ShawnTaylor: It's not so much that I reversed the order, as that I put the lookbehind before the `"` and the lookahead after the `"`. Their relative order doesn't matter, but their exact positions do. (For example, the regex `(?!\|)"(?<!\|)` would be equivalent to the regex `"`, because the lookahead and lookbehind would both just be asserting that the `"` is not a pipe.)